# Cambiar Campo a Atributo en XML TARGET - PowerCenter

Tags: xml

Tengo un `Mapping` funcionando,el cual tiene como fuente 4 tablas desde Oracle y son traspasadas a un `target` de tipo `XML`.

Este archivo `XML` se genera de la siguiente forma:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<X_PURCHASEORDERS>
    <X_PURCHASEORDER>
        <X_ADDRESS>
            <XPK_ADDRESS>1</XPK_ADDRESS>
            <TYPE>Shipping</TYPE>
            <NAME>Cristian Osorio</NAME>
            <STREET>123 Mk</STREET>
            <CITY>Buffalo</CITY>
            <STATE>NY</STATE>
            <ZIP>98112</ZIP>
            <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        </X_ADDRESS>
        <X_ADDRESS>
            <XPK_ADDRESS>2</XPK_ADDRESS>
            <TYPE>Billing</TYPE>
            <NAME>Ko Lee</NAME>
            <STREET>789 BV</STREET>
            <CITY>Buffalo</CITY>
            <STATE>NY</STATE>
            <ZIP>98112</ZIP>
            <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        </X_ADDRESS>
        <X_ITEM>
            <XPK_ITEM>1</XPK_ITEM>
            <PARTNUMBER>897-AA</PARTNUMBER>
            <PRODUCTNAME>DSADSFRSDF</PRODUCTNAME>
            <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
            <USPRICE>125</USPRICE>
            <COMMENTS>A</COMMENTS>
            <SHIPDATE>11-12-2005</SHIPDATE>
        </X_ITEM>
        <X_ITEM>
            <XPK_ITEM>2</XPK_ITEM>
            <PARTNUMBER>897-AE</PARTNUMBER>
            <PRODUCTNAME>OIUOYUI</PRODUCTNAME>
            <QUANTITY>5</QUANTITY>
            <USPRICE>1</USPRICE>
            <COMMENTS>E</COMMENTS>
            <SHIPDATE>11-12-2005</SHIPDATE>
        </X_ITEM>
        <XPK_PURCHASEORDER>1</XPK_PURCHASEORDER>
        <ORDERDATE>1990-10-20</ORDERDATE>
        <PURCHASEORDERNUMBER>99503</PURCHASEORDERNUMBER>
        <DELIVERYNOTES>Comments</DELIVERYNOTES>
    </X_PURCHASEORDER>
 <X_PURCHASEORDERS>
```

pero necesito que algunos elementos pasen a ser atributos.

EJEMPLO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<X_PURCHASEORDERS>
    <X_PURCHASEORDER>
        ***<X_ADDRESS XPK_ADDRESS="1" TYPE="Shipping">***
            <NAME>Cristian Osorio</NAME>
            <STREET>123 Mk</STREET>
            <CITY>Buffalo</CITY>
            <STATE>NY</STATE>
            <ZIP>98112</ZIP>
            <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        </X_ADDRESS>
       </X_PURCHASEORDER>
   </X_PURCHASEORDERS>
```

Mapping:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbUxf.png

XML Target:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida Josefina!, trata de exponer con un poco más de detalle cual es el problema y que haz realizado!

Comment: Listo, agregue mas informacion